# Multi Timezone - How to store/print data properly

Tags: php, mysql, database, timezone

I'm working on a website that lives in multiple timezones.
My question is what is the best way to store date/time records.

My approach:

1. Set PHP environment to "Europe/London" and save all data in that timezone e.g. 2011-02-11 22:00:00
2. Get client timezone e.g. +8hours
3. Calculate datetime + client timezone difference = 2011-02-12 06:00:00

Is that the optimal way or is there a better?

Comment: For me, I prefer a standard timezone and all clients timezone, e.g. +2 or +8 will be in reference to mine

Comment: I know this is an old question, but the problem with it is that it is devoid of any _context_.  Not all date and time data has the same requirements.  For example, storing a birthday like `1980-11-23` is very different than storing a timestamp like `2024-01-09T20:00:00.000Z` or a scheduled future event such as `2025-06-10T11:00:00[Europe/London]`.  One-size-fits-all solutions like "always use UTC" are ill-advised, and lead to bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store everything as UTC, and use the client's regional settings to display the local date/time.

Answer (score 1):

1. Save all your times in UTC.
2. Use the [built-in PHP date and time functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) to convert.  In particular, see [date_timezone_set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-timezone-set.php).